# How to remove duplicate code if I create array with different number of elements?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some duplicate code:

```
var client = new RSClient.RSClient();

var Params = new RsParameter[1];
Params[0] = new RsParameter {Key = "order_id", Value = orderId};
var result = client.GetPreparedReportSimple(login, password, "CREDO_ORDER", Params);

var client = new RSClient.RSClient();

var Params = new RsParameter[2];
Params[0] = new RsParameter {Key = "calculation_id", Value = calculationId};
Params[1] = new RsParameter {Key = "calculation_date", Value = calculationDate};
var result = client.GetPreparedReportSimpleExport(login, password, "CREDO_RSV_ACTIVE", Params, "XLS");
```

How can I do this better?

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by "better"?

Comment: Better meaning exactly what `Oscar Mederos` has recommended

Comment: Where is the duplicate code here?

Comment: Otiel I think that he thinks this is the duplicate lines 
`var result = client.GetPreparedReportSimple(login, password, "CREDO_ORDER", Params);` & `var result = client.GetPreparedReportSimpleExport(login, password, "CREDO_RSV_ACTIVE", Params, "XLS");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first ,

```
 1- move the export and simple display functionality into 2 different methods.
 2- Create a Client Object exactly once by using Singleton Pattern.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code and extract a method. It would be something like this:

```
public __?___ Method(string login, string password, string something, string[] parameters, string extra = null) {
    var client = new RSClient.RSClient();

    if (extra == null)
        return client.GetPreparedReportSimple(login, password, something, parameters);
    else
        return client.GetPreparedReportSimple(login, password, something, parameters, extra);
}
```

once you have it, you call it like this:

```
var Params = new [] 
    {
        new RsParameter {Key = "order_id", Value = orderId} 
    };
var result = Method(login, password, "CREDO_ORDER", Params);

....

var Params = new [] 
    {
        new RsParameter {Key = "calculation_id", Value = calculationId},
        new RsParameter {Key = "calculation_date", Value = calculationDate}
    };
var result = Method(login, password, "CREDO_ORDER", params, "XLS");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop to iterate and skip repeating code, in the case you have more thay two cases. Just make a var with your different data (strings, etc) for each iteration:

```
keys= new[]
{
    "order_id",
    "calculation_id",
    //etc
}
```